# Subclassing UIImageView and adding a UIControl

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I'm trying to subclass the UIImageView to add a UIControl to it so i know when it is selected:

```
-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size OffImage:(UIImage *)offImage onImage:(UIImage *)onImage
{
    if (self) {
        [self setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
        self.userInteractionEnabled = TRUE;

        [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[self(80)]"
                                                                     options:0
                                                                     metrics:@{@"WIDTH" : [NSNumber numberWithFloat:size.width]}
                                                                       views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(self)]];

        [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[self(90)]"
                                                                     options:0
                                                                     metrics:@{@"HEIGHT" : [NSNumber numberWithFloat:size.height]}
                                                                       views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(self)]];

        self.offImage = offImage;
        self.onImage = onImage;
        self.selected = FALSE;

        UIControl *control = [[UIControl alloc] init];
        [control setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
        self.control = control;

        [self addSubview:control];

        [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[control]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(control)]];
        [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[control]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(control)]];

    }

    return self;
}
```

When i try to add the constraints to make the UIControl the same size as the subclassed UIImageView, i get an error saying that self.control does not have a superview:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse constraint format: 
Unable to interpret '|' character, because the related view doesn't have a superview 
H:|[control]| 
            ^'
```

If i do this same type of thing by creating a UIImageView, then create a UIControl and `[imageView addsubview:control]`, it works just fine. Why is it crashing when i try to add the same code to the `init` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How did you create your imageView Subclass object? In this code there is no [Super init..]

Comment: bah, that was it, thanks! I forgot `self = [super init]`. Now I feel silly.